# Base de datos relaciones

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Tengo 3 tablas:

> Marca
>   Modelo
>   Conector

Una marca tiene muchos modelos

Un modelo pertenece a una sola marca

Un conector pertenece a una o muchas marcas/modelos

> Como puedo relacionarlas de modo que cuando yo pregunte por marca y modelo me 
>   muestre todos los conectores disponibles, actualmente la tengo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna otra sugerencia en mi base de datos y también su opinión, si la ven factible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algo mas o menos asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una marca tiene muchos modelos, un conector tiene muchos modelo/marca, un modelo solo pertenece a una marca:

[Script Mysql](https://pastebin.com/BYLGMcD5)

Después le cargas algunos registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y despues haces unos joins entre las tablas para ir relacionandolas y obtener la info:

```
select ma.detMarca, mo.detModelo, co.detConector
from conector_x_modelo cxm inner join conector co on co.idConector = 
cxm.idConector_FK
inner join modelo mo on mo.idModelo = cxm.idModelo_FK
inner join marca ma on ma.idMarca = mo.idMarca_FK
```

[Funcionamientos de joins mysql](https://guru99.es/joins/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si solo queres una marca le pones la condicion del where con el id de la marca o con el detalle como hago en el ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan, me ayudaste a entender :)